# Axios Plugin in Nuxt 3

Tags: axios, nuxtjs3

I try to configure Axios in nuxt 3 using a plugin.
As I studied the [documentation](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/plugins), plugin require in `nuxt.config` is no longer needed to I created the file right away in my plugins folder:

```
export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
  const domain = 'http://localhost:3000/v1/'
  const username = "abcdef"
  const password = "123456"
  const token = `${username}:${password}`
  const encodedToken = Buffer.from(token).toString('base64')

  let publicApi = nuxtApp.$axios.create({
    baseUrl: domain,
    headers: {
      common: {
        Authorization: `Basic ${encodedToken}`
      }
    }
  })

  return {
    provide: {
      publicApi: publicApi
    }
  }
})
```

I then try to call the newly injected variable in my components:

```
this.$publicApi.$get('some_endpoint')
```

which fires a request via axios successfully but the previously configured `baseUrl` and `headers` are empty so it seems that my axios instance was not created somehow.

What am I doing wwrong?

Comment: You could probably even use a composable directly, rather than a plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wrong syntax used
this is correct:

`baseURL: domain`

now it works